# How to show content of text box when I hover mouse on text box

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am creating above text box in my JSP file which getting populated in javascript(basically content inside textbox is dynamic not static).  I want to display the content of text box when I take mouse over text box. Is there any function in javascript I can use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onmouseover` event handler. Modify the input's text using the `value` property. You can also use an `onmouseout` event handler to clear the text when the mouse leaves the input if you need it. See it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gexsK/).

For instance:

```
 <input id="anId" type="text" 
        onmouseover="this.value=calculateText(this.id)" 
        onmouseout="this.value=''">
```

Just in case you'd like to do the same thing when the `<input>` gets/loses the focus (by <kbd>TAB</kbd> for instance), use the `onfocus` and `onblur` event handlers.

**UPDATE** It turns out the OP wanted to dynamically change the `title` attribute of the input, so that it pops up in a tooltip when the mouse hovers over it. This can be achieved adding an <strike>`onkeyup`</strike>`oninput` event handler to the component that sets `this.title` to `this.value`. Learn more about `oninput` [here](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript).

```
<input  type="text" oninput="this.title = this.value">
```

Comment: I tried what you explained above, but  I take mouse over it, it says internet explorer exception, object expected. I think  its not getting javascript function calculateText. It’s a guess. Let me again brief you what I am trying to do here, when I take mouse over  my text box , whatever the value inside textbox, it should be displayed  on top of that so that even if the value inside textbox is too large user can see it when it takes mouse over it.

Comment: `calculateText` is just the name of a function I made up, that should return the dynamic content you were referring to in the question. Let me know if I'm getting what you mean now, you want to display whatever text the input has even if it is larger than the input size ? Sort of a text overlay over the input field?

Comment: It just came to my mind a possible answer to what you seem to be asking. You can show small text pieces when the mouse stops on an element (like a tooltip) by using the `title` attribute. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gexsK/5/) for an example that dinamycally updates the `title` attribute with the value of the input box in the `onKeyUp` event handler.

Comment: let me give you example  what i am trying to do  here.As  when i take my over your reputation given below your name on this forum i.e 3650 at this point of time, it says reputation score.similarly if my tex box contains the name scott and when i take mouse over it, it should show the content of textbox(which is scott in this case) in the same fashion.

Comment: That is a tooltip, the contents of which are extracted from the `title` attribute. Have you looked at the fiddle I gave? http://jsfiddle.net/gexsK/5/

Comment: Use oninput instead onkeyup. It's faster and supports a wider range of inputs.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable comment, @Amaan. I didn't know about `oninput`. I appreciate it.